# Example of a Lebesgue measurable function which is not a Baire function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions, lebesgue-measure

I found the following statement on Wikipedia :

> "Henri Lebesgue proved that (for functions on the unit interval) each Baire class of a countable ordinal number contains functions not in any smaller class, and that there exist functions which are not in any Baire class."

I know that any non-measurable function can't be a member of any Baire class. But a proof of this kind requires the axiom of choice (for existence of a non-measurable set).

Did Lebesgue use AC in his proof? If not can anyone provide an example of a measurable function that is not in any Baire class?

(Or was Lebesgue's proof not constructive?)

**ADDED:** On [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BaireFunction.html) I found the following statement:

> Lebesgue showed that each of the Baire classes is nonempty and that **there are** **(Lebesgue-)** **measurable functions that are not Baire functions** (Kleiner 1989).

So now the question winds down to: **Can anyone give a sketch of a proof for this?** or better yet **an example of such a function?**

Comment: Here's the paper, published in 1905, by Lebesgue: [*Sur les fonctions représentables analytiquement*](http://portail.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/JMPA_1905_6_1_A5_0.pdf). You may want to try a [google-phrase search for its title](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Sur+les+fonctions+repr%C3%A9sentables+analytiquement%22) to see what turns up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's simpler than i previously thought.

The [Borel functions coincide with the Baire functions](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1974-194-00/S0002-9947-1974-0362270-7/S0002-9947-1974-0362270-7.pdf) (on suitable topological spaces).

So any indicator function of a [Lebesgue measurable set that is not Borel measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141017/lebesgue-measurable-set-that-is-not-a-borel-measurable-set) will do.