# Proof that a homeomorphic image of a non-borel set is non-borel

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

This question seeks to expand the proof given in the answer to [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141017/lebesgue-measurable-set-that-is-not-a-borel-measurable-set)

I am weak in topology, and am wondering if someone can provide a proof of why a homeomorphic image of a non-borel set is non-borel?

Comment: What is a "topological map"?

Comment: Given that the linked thread describes the use of a homeomorphism between $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$, constructed using the Cantor function, I assume that *topological map* = *homeomorphism* here.

Comment: @Wojowu I have edit the post to say "topological mapping" by which I mean some mapping $f$ from one topological space $X$ to another topological space $Y$; i.e. $f : X \to Y$.

Comment: Möbius, the claim is obviously false in that generality. And I'm positive the answerer there did not mean that.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Okay I will edit the post to be more specific, as per your comment.

Comment: Hint: A homeomorphism is continuous, bijective, and has a continuous inverse. Now, continuous functions are Borel measurable. Assume $f(B)$ is measurable for a homeomorphism $f$. Could $B$ be non-measurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a homeomorphism $f: X \to Y$ is continuous, it is also Borel-measurable. The same is true of $f^{-1}: Y \to X$.

Let $\mathcal{B}_{x}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{y}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Since $f$ is measurable we know that for every $B_{1} \in \mathcal{B}_{y}$ we have that $f^{-1}(B_{1}) \in \mathcal{B}_{x}$, and that for every $B_{2} \in \mathcal{B}_{x}$ we have that $f(B_{2}) \in \mathcal{B}_{y}$.

Let $B_{0} \subset X$ be a non-Borel set. Then $B_{0} \notin \mathcal{B}_{x}$. Since for every $B_{1} \in \mathcal{B}_{y}$ we have that $f^{-1}(B_{1}) \in \mathcal{B}_{x}$, it must be that there is no set in $\mathcal{B}_{y}$ that is mapped to $B_{0}$ (i.e. no Borel set in $Y$ can be mapped by $f$ to a non-Borel set in $X$).

The same holds if $B_{0} \subset Y$ is not Borel; no Borel set in $X$ can be mapped by $f$ to a non-Borel set in $Y$.

By the fact that $f$ is bijective, this implies that no non-Borel set $B_{0} \subset X$ can be mapped to a Borel set $f(B_{0})$ as otherwise $f^{-1} (f (B_{0}))= B_{0}$ must be Borel (since borel sets are mapped to borel sets), which is a contradiction. The same holds for non-borel sets $B_{0} \subset Y$.

Therefore, a homeomorphic image of a non-borel set must be non-borel.