# Size of countable product $\sigma$-algebra of power set

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $\Omega = \{\; 0, 1 \;\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be the set of all functions $\mathbb{N} \to \{\; 0, 1 \;\}$.
Then $\displaystyle\mathcal{F} = \bigotimes_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{P}(\{\; 0, 1 \;\})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, where $\mathcal{P}(\dots)$ denotes the power set and $\bigotimes$ the product-$\sigma$-algebra.

Is $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$?
This seems unlikely, but how would one construct a non $\mathcal{F}$-measurable set? As $(\{\; 0, 1 \;\}, \mathcal{P}(\{\; 0, 1 \;\}))$ is a polish space, one can prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra generated by the product topology on $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: \Omega \to C$ be a homeomorphism between $\Omega$ and a [fat Cantor subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) $C$ of $[0,1]$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429674/homeomorphism-between-two-cantor-sets)).

Since $C$ has positive Lebesgue measure, it has a non-measurable subset $A$. Then, $f^{-1}(A)$ is non-measurable.

For more details, see [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403829/proof-that-a-homeomorphic-image-of-a-non-borel-set-is-non-borel).

Comment: Thanks! Though not as constructive as I had hoped, the proof seems to check out.