# A non-Borel Lebesgue measurable set hat is a subset of a measurable zero Borel st

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

We know that the subset $N$ of $[0,1) \subset \mathbb R$ that contains exactly one member of the equivalence classes of $\sim$ defined on $[0,1)$, where $x \sim y$ iff $x - y$ is rational, is an example of a Lebesgue set that is not a Borel set. Is $N$ a subset of a measure zero Borel set? This seems to be true since intuitively it seems like we can shrink the size of $N$ arbitarily small, but I cannot prove it at the moment. If so, how can we find such a Borel superset?

More generally, is it true that any uncountable Borel set $E$ contains a subset that is a Lebesgue measurable set but not a Borel set?

Comment: Isn't this actually an example of a non Lebesgue measurable set? And as such, it can't be contained in a set of measure zero. (since the Lebesgue measure is complete)

Answer (score 0):

*is it true that any uncountable Borel set $E$ contains a subset that is a Lebesgue measurable set but not a Borel set?*

Yes.  An uncountable Borel set $E$ contains a subset $F$ homeomorphic to the Cantor set.  We may assume $F$ has Lebesgue measure zero.  Argue by cardinality:  There are $\mathfrak c = 2^{\aleph_0}$ Borel subsets of $F$, but there are $2^{\mathfrak c}$ subsets (and all subsets are Lebesgue measurable null sets).  Thus, there is a Lebesgue measurable subset that is not Borel.

---

Is this a duplicate question?  For example, [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1742137/442)