# Lebesgue Measure - (Rudin Real and Complex analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

My problem is this statement

> $\mathfrak{M}$ contains all Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^k$; more precisely, $E\in \mathfrak{M}$ if and only if there are sets $A$ and $B\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $A\subset E\subset B$, $A$ is an $F_\sigma$, $B$ is a $G_\delta$, and $m(B-A)=0$. Also, m is regular.

Why is it that

> $\mathfrak{M}$ contains all Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^k$

is equivalent to

> $E\in \mathfrak{M}$ if and only if there are sets $A$ and $B\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $A\subset E\subset B$, $A$ is an $F_\sigma$, $B$ is a $G_\delta$, and $m(B-A)=0.$

Comment: Why do you think they're equivalent?

Comment: They are not equivalent. The former is included in the latter.

Comment: @zhw. I assumed it was implied when he said "more precisely". In my mind the second statement is saying that $E\in \mathfrak{M}$ if it is borel almost everywhere (which is the strongest statement you can make about a set when given its measure). But I don't really see how both statements are exactly the same.

Comment: @HenryW. Do you mean to say that there are sets which aren't borel yet still measurable?

Comment: @user160110 Indeed. Such examples are pathological and can be found by considering the Cantor set. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141017/lebesgue-measurable-set-that-is-not-a-borel-measurable-set)

Comment: I would agree that "more precisely" is strange word usage there. That first clause is perfectly precise; it needs no further explanation. Rather than "more precisely", Rudin could have said "More is true: ... " to better effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two statements you mention are not equivalent.

Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be a $\sigma-$algebra containing the Borel sets, then equivalent are the following two statements:

> $\mathfrak{M}$ is the minimum complete $\sigma-$algebra which contains all Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^k$

and

> $E\in \mathfrak{M}$ if and only if there are sets $A$ and $B\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $A\subset E\subset B$, $A$ is an $F_\sigma$, $B$ is a $G_\delta$, and $m(B-A)=0.$

Comment: Ahh so first statement is the borel $\sigma$-algebra and the second statement is the completed borel $\sigma$-algebra.