# Can any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ be generated from open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Can any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ be generated by taking countable unions, countable intersections and complements of open intervals?

Clearly, singletons can be generated from the complement of the union of half-rays, e.g.: $$a=((-\infty, a) \cup (a, \infty))^C .$$

Closed intervals can also be generated by a countable intersection of open sets of the form $(a- \frac1n, b+\frac1n)$ and similarly for half-open intervals.

From this, it seems obvious that any *countable* union/intersection of intervals can be generated.

How about for example *uncountable* unions/intersections of intervals?  It is unclear to me whether this is enough to generate *all* subsets of  $\mathbb{R}$. Can this be done?

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is the complement of $\Bbb Q$...

Comment: @TonyK Of course it is :)  I was too focused on trying to deal with the uncountability of the irrationals, and missed the obvious...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be "created" by this process. If it were possible, we would get that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra would contain all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, which it does not.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any simple example of a subset of $R$ that isn't a Borel set?

Comment: Not really, all examples of non-Borel measurable sets depend on the axiom of choice (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32720/non-borel-sets-without-axiom-of-choice). However, a short example is this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141017/lebesgue-measurable-set-that-is-not-a-borel-measurable-set

Answer (score 3):

______Editing my comment to extend the answer_______________

Hint: There is an example for Lebesgue but not Borel measurable sets.

Additionally:-

If you're familiar with measure theory, then there's a couple results that are somewhat related to this matter.

1. Every non-empty open subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a disjoint union of open intervals.
2. Littlewood's first principle of Analysis

Every measurable set $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ with $m(E)<$ $\infty$ is almost a finite union of intervals.

Comment: I know some measure theory, but perhaps not enough to understand all of what you're saying.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the hint.