# Why is $\mu$-measurable set contained in the Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I am reading the final chapter of baby rudin. I have trouble understanding the difference between   $\mu$-*measurable* sets and the Borel sets. The remarks on page 309 imply that the latter is contained in the former. But from the way I see it, they are both the collection of sets, which are the final forms of open intervals after undergoing intersections, taking complements and unions. So what exactly are $\mu$-*measurable* sets? And why are the Borel sets $\mu$-*measurable* for every $\mu$?

Comment: Welcome to mse! I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking why every borel set is $\mu$-measurable (where I assume $\mu$ is lebesgue measure?)? Or are you asking why there are $\mu$-measurable sets that are not borel?

Comment: So yes, all Borel sets are measurable. There should be an example somewhere of a set defined using the Cantor function of a measurable set that is not Borel.

Comment: Also, $\mu$ is not a variable, $\mu$ is shorthand for *the* Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Hi ! I think $\mu$ can be any measure, not just the lebesgue measure. I am very confused about the concept of $\mu-measurable$ sets. Are they defined for any measure, i.e.a collection of measurable sets or they only refer to one particular measure?

Comment: @ndhanson3 I think Rudin uses $m$ for the Lebesgue measure and $\mu$ for any kind of measure

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141017/lebesgue-measurable-set-that-is-not-a-borel-measurable-set) has the construction but it's involved. It is hard to find borel sets which aren't lebesgue measurable but they exist.

Comment: @DanielApsley You mean Lebesgue measurable but not Borel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any measure $\mu$, remark (a) says that the open sets are $\mu$-measurable. A set $E$ is $\mu$-measurable simply if $\mu(E)$ is defined. Not every set is measurable though.

So the set of measurable sets $\mathfrak{M}(\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets. Since the Borel set is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets, $\mathfrak{M}(\mu)$ must contain all the Borel sets. This is indeed regardless of what measure we start with.