# Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ with $\lambda^*(A)>0$. Show that there exists a nonmeasurable $B\subseteq\Bbb R$ s.t. $B\subseteq A$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A$ be a subset of $\Bbb R$ with $\lambda^*(A)>0$. Show that there exists a nonmeasurable subset $B$ of $\Bbb R$ s.t. $B$ is a subset of $A$

I'm a little confused where to start with this one. If $A$ is nonmeasurable there is nothing to prove so we have to assume that $A$ is measurable, more specifically a nonzero measure. Define an equivalence class next?? not sure....

Comment: What exactly is $\lambda^*(A)$ here?

Comment: @aschepler: Presumably Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: yes, @aschepler, it means the outer measure generated by the Lebesgue measure on R

Comment: Have you seen the construction of a [Vitali set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set)?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott have seen it in text but have not done too much work using it. my thinking here is use the Axiom of choice to show there exists a subset B of A containing precisely one member from each equivalence class. let {r1, r2, ....} be an enumeration of the rationals [-1,1] and let Bn=rn+B. Im still working on how to show this and finish from here

Comment: You can’t guarantee that each equivalence class meets $A$, but you can use the axiom of choice to say that there is a $B\subseteq A$ such that if an equivalence class actually intersects $A$, then $B$ contains exactly one member of that class. However, before you do that you should replace $A$ by $A\cap[n,n+1]$ for some $n$ such that $\lambda^*(A\cap[n,n+1])>0$, so that you’re working with a bounded set.

Comment: what if, following from my previous comment, i stated that the sequence {Bn} is pairwise disjoint, lamda*(Bn)=lamda*(B) holds for each n and that A is a subset of the union from 1 to infinity of Bn which is a subset of [-1,2]. Noting that if B is a measurable set, then each Bn is  measurable set, proof by contradiction? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: Not a subset of $[-1,2]$, but rather of $[n-1,n+2]$, but otherwise you’re okay: $A$ has positive measure, so the sets $B_n$ cannot be null sets, but then their union can’t be a subset of the finite interval $[n-1,n+2]$.

Comment: Look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206618/positive-outer-measure-set-and-nonmeasurable-subset