# Borel set's incompleteness

Tags: measure-theory

I was told that while M, class of all Lebesgue measurable set is complete, sigma field generated by all open set B is not. Can someone give me an example of interval which is inside M yet is not included in B? Thank you.

Comment: Look at the subsets of the Cantor set.

Comment: thank you for your answer. because of that, I manage to find this discussion. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206618/positive-outer-measure-set-and-nonmeasurable-subset