# A question about Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is there a set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that Lebesgue outer measure is countably additive on subsets of $X$? Of course we also require $X$ to have positive outer measure.

Comment: No. I'll try to write it up soon.Outer measure is translation-invariant,which may play a role in the proof.

Comment: This (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206618/positive-outer-measure-set-and-nonmeasurable-subset) might help.

Comment: If $X$ has no closed subsets of cardinality strictly between $\aleph_0$ and $\mathfrak c$, then the usual Bernstein set construction works. This resolves the problem under CH. A similar argument should work if you assume Martin's axiom (as then all closed sets of cardinality under $\mathfrak c$ are null, I guess). I wouldn't be surprised if it turned out to be independent of ZFC. Are you sure it's true? Is it an exercise, or a problem of your own?