# Example of function that is not Borel measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Could you provide an example of a function $f$ from $[0,1]^2$ to $[0,1]$ that is not Borel measurable? Is requiring $f$ to be Borel meusurable very restrictive?

Comment: Can you find a subset $A\subset[0,1]^2$ that is not Borel-measurable? Then the characteristic function of $A$ is not Borel-measurable. No, it is not very restrictive. Your question on itself testifies.

Comment: Thanks. To help me understanding better, could you give an example of $A$?

Comment: Any Lebesgue-non measurabel set is not Borel-measurable (contraposition, Borel measurability implies the Lebesgue one). It could be for example, the Vitali set. Consider the relation $a\sim b\iff b-a$ is rational. Vitali set is the set of representants of cosets.

Comment: You could also take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137277/75923)