# Can anyone give me an example of a measurable subset of the interval [10,100], that is not a Borel set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I know how to construct a measurable set of a Cantor set that is not Borel but the example will be of the form $f^{-1}(E)$ is a subset of cantor set and is measurable (where $f$ is homeomorphism from Cantor set to a set of positive outer measure).
So I would like an example of a measurable subset of the interval (say [10,100]), that is not a Borel set.

Comment: Without Axiom of Choice?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/140582/44121

Comment: Why not scale and translate the set you already have?